# Why reloading google chrome tab via extension switches accounts?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a following illustrative extension that will terminate tab process and reload page if user visits "www.ru":

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "name" : "test extension",
  "version" : "1.0.0",
  "permissions" : [ "tabs", "experimental" ],
  "background" : { "scripts" : [ "extension.js" ], "persistent" : true }
}
```

`extension.js`

```
function reload() {
    chrome.tabs.query( {}, function( tabs ) {
        for( var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i ++ ) {
            if( tabs[ i ].url.match( /www\.ru/ ) ) {
                window.setTimeout( function() {
                    chrome.experimental.processes.getProcessIdForTab( tabs[ i ].id, function( id ) {
                        chrome.experimental.processes.terminate( id );
                    })
                }, 5000);
                window.setTimeout( function() {
                    chrome.tabs.reload( tabs[ i ].id );
                }, 10000);
                return;
            }
        }
        window.setTimeout( reload, 1000 );
    });
}
window.setTimeout( reload, 1000 );
```

I start latest google chrome (26.0.1410.64 m 32-bit for windows downloaded from chrome.google.com minutes ago), create second chrome user, switch to that user, install extension, open 'www.ru', switch to first user - and after 10 seconds chrome forcibly switches me back to second user in order to demonstrate tab reload!

Only process kill + tab reload produces this weird behavior (they pause in between can be any length). If terminate or reload parts are commented out, corresponding action is carried but user account is newer switched.

Is it some chrome bug i'm facing or this is documented behavior? Is it possible to prevent forcible account switch? It's very unpleasant for me to be interrupted in the middle of something just to display that some web crawler extension on web crawler account found tab that is not responding and reloaded it :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eye of Hell, this answer is an educated guess. It's possible that Chrome uses a heuristic to determine whether a tab should become the active tab during a load or reload. The heuristic might be that the first load/reload for the tab process should make it the active tab, unless the tab was explicitly created with createProperties active: false. This would make sense if you think of a new tab's default for the active state, and understand that at process creation time (including the process creation after a terminate/reload), the tab is likely set to that default.

If this is true, then instead of reloading the tab after killing its process, perhaps you could do this instead:

1. Remember the about-to-be-killed tab's URL.
2. Kill the process and close the tab OR just close the tab.
3. chrome.tabs.create({url: savedUrl, active: false}).

It's possible that this has some other undesirable side effects, such as losing session cookies. But without knowing more about your use case, this seems like an equivalent approach to what you're trying to do.

By the way, your recovery process could be faster. Rather than setting the 5-second and 10-second timeouts to serialize the kill/reload operations, you can chain the reload (or create) operation in the terminate function's callback. Then it's guaranteed to be called after the terminate is complete, and it won't waste wall-clock time waiting for the extra five seconds.